# ssl causing infinite loop with wordpress frontend

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, ssl

SSL not working for WordPress website. Please help me to resolve this.

Comment: Please help, this need to be resolved . I am tired now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the dashboard:

- Go to Settings -> General
- Make sure WordPress Address (URL) and Site Address (URL) are https://www.thebookelves.com/ and not http://www.thebookelves.com/

Comment: I have done that. But still infinite loop on fron-end of website.

Comment: Can you try clearing the cache from your browser/try another browser? I'm not getting an infinite loop.

Comment: Have you opened with https?

Comment: It first only redirected to http. What's the contents of your htaccess?

Comment: # BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress